# Default implementation of Sun's web service specification?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

What is the default implementation of Sun's web service specification? And how I can start with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reference Implementation of JAX-WS is [Metro](http://jax-ws.java.net/).

The easiest way to start programming with JAX-WS is to [follow the Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html).

What JAX-WS implementation you should use depends on your circumstances. If you use NetBeans with Glassfish, Metro comes bundled with both the IDE and the Java EE server. If you want to use special features of other implementations, you can easily exchange Metro for CXF, for example.

From [the CXF site](https://cxf.apache.org/):

> CXF implements the JAX-WS APIs (TCK compliant). CXF JAX-WS support includes some extensions to the standard that make it significantly easier to use, compared to the reference implementation: It will automatically generate code for request and response bean classes, and does not require a WSDL for simple cases.

If you need these extensions, use CXF.

Comment: What about this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/index.html

Is this old implementation? Axis2 also uses jax-ws if I am not wrong.

Comment: That is quite old (February 17, 2006). I don't know how well it covers Java EE 5. It does *not* cover the current Java EE 6, which was released in 2009.